# update elasticsearch data by using elasticserch dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

How can I update **elasticsearch** data by using [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package? Is that possible ?
I found [elasticsearch update api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), but it seems like bit difficult. What I am looking for is,

```
searchObj = Search(using=logserver, index=INDEX)
searchObj=searchObj.query("term",attribute=value).update(attribute=new_value)
response = searchObj.execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

@kingArther answer is not correct.

`elasticsearch-dsl` support update very well!

By mapping an index to an object (DocType) it allows 
you to save and update easily without any JSON rest requests.

You can find examples an API [here](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html?highlight=update)

Answer (score 1):

Its probably late but i am leaving this reply for those who are still having same issue:
elasticsearch-dsl offers update function that can be called on classes extending Document class of elasticsearch-dsl. Following is the code:

```
data = yourIndexClass.get(id=documentIdInIndex)
data.update(key=NewValue)
```

That is it. Simple. [Find details Here](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html?highlight=update)

Comment: i think its python

Comment: can you add some references ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong `elasticsearch_dsl` doesn't have an option for update/bulk update.
So, if you like, you can use [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) pckage for the same.
**Example**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

INDEX = 'myindex'
LOG_HOST = 'myhost:myport'
logserver = Elasticsearch(LOG_HOST)

script = "ctx._source.attribute = new_value"

update_body = {

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {"attribute": "value"}
            }
        }
    },

    "script": {
        "source": script,
        "lang": "painless"

    }

}

update_response = logserver.update_by_query(index=INDEX, body=update_body)
```

For more information, see this [official documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=update#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update_by_query)

Comment: its not correct, elasticsearch-dsl does support update very well